# having issue to order result mysql, php

Tags: mysql

My code has no problem. The thing I want to achieve is that I want to order the result. First, I want it `order by lev DESC` from highest number to lowest, look at code, `5,4,3`. However, since I have duplicate `dis`, so it only read the first low `lev`, if the first row is `5`, second low is `4`, But it always order by the first row number.  how to achieve what I want, appreciate.

```
dis sym cat val lev
1   44  on  2   5
1   45  set 3   3
2   44  set 2   5
2   45  set 3   5
3   44  on  2   5
3   44  set 5   4

SELECT DISTINCT dis from my_table where dis IN(%s,%s,%s) AND 
dis NOT IN ( SELECT dis FROM my_table 
where (( cat = 'on' and val !=%d ) or ( cat = 'set' and val !=%d )) 
AND sym=%d AND lev > 3) 
AND sym=%d ORDER BY lev DESC
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want: please provide desired output.

Comment: Thanks for response. I figure it myself. In case others want to see the solution.  Use min(lev) DESC to get the min number in duplicate row, and then use GROUP BY instead of INSTINCT to count(dis). and then order by the count DESC.